# Why does Loess Fit not extend over all datapoints in shiny app?

Tags: r, loess

In a shiny app I developed, I'm fitting a number of Loess curves over the `ozone` datset (temperature vs ozone levels [ppm]). [See Link.](https://mzhku.shinyapps.io/course_project/)

I wonder why the Loess fits (and the associated average over all fits, the red line) do not extend over all datapoints.

I believe I'm setting up the fit such that for every data point a prediction is to be made ([see line 23 in the code](https://github.com/mzhKU/loess_fit_app/blob/master/server.R)).

In my local version of the app, the fit -at least visually- is over all datapoints.
[image]

Comment: I don't think I'm following.  How are you using the word "over".  The loess fits seems to extend over the entire range of your data.

Comment: Isn't ozone more nearly a response to temperature rather than _vice versa_?

Comment: @MatthewDrury In the screenshot yes, but that's from my local app- not from the shiny app. That's the discrepancy I'm pointing at.

Comment: @NickCox I'm merely reproducing an example from a slideshow. The physical nature doesn't matter that much in this exercise.